# Problem regarding Gauss's Lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

In Gauss'Lemma is it necessary for $a$ in
$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ to be a prime? I've checked a couple of books but there seems to be no restriction of this kind on $a$ just that $a$ and $p$ should be relatively prime. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are you thinking about finding the sign by counting some jumps for residues when multiplied by $a$? No, $a$ does not need to be prime, just not a multiple of $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not necessary.

The reason you are likely seeing this, is because since Legendre symbols are fully multiplicative it suffices to show that it is only true for when $a$ is a prime. Since all integers $a$ can be factored into primes and then decomposed into a product of Legendre symbols with primes on top.